# 6 months old iPhone 6s battery disabled peak power

Tags: iphone, battery, repair, warranty

I had my iPhone 6s battery replaced by Apple in November last year (i.e. 5,5 months ago). Today the phone crashed and [peak power was disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208387) again. Admittedly it was relatively cold outside (about 8°C) and I used the phone for navigation. Battery health is given as 98%.

Nevertheless, I am rather annoyed that an almost new battery dies on me and I wonder if I should complain. Is the replaced battery covered by any kind of warranty and does it extent to peak power capability?

Comment: 8C is 46.4F, so I'm not sure temperature is a factor. -8C is 17.6F, which is below freezing, but not low enough, IMHO, to cause such a problem so quickly.

Comment: @IconDaemon Before I had the battery replaced, I knew that my battery would reliably die if temperatures were around 0°C / 32°F and battery charge below 90%. So I basically always carryied a battery pack with me in winter.

Comment: The best way to find out is to go by the Apple store you had the work done at and explain the issue.